# how to add online jars to manifest classpath

Tags: java, maven, manifest

My idea is to create a jar file with classes and manifest with jar dependencies over the network.
Now for this, I created a small java class and added some libs like Lombok and slf4j API, while building the classes I got the class files and created a manual manifest file as below:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: packagemain.MainClass
Class-Path: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.8/lombok-1.18.8.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar

I added the jar links online directly to classpath in manifest and I packed these files into a jar by using the command:
jar cfvm myJar.jar MANIFEST.MF *

**Now while running I am still getting the error as below:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at packagemain.MainClass.(MainClass.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 1 more

Can anyone help me and let me know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: I doubt you can use a classpath in this way. If I were you, I would just do it like everybody else.

Comment: (1) You _are_ running this with `java -jar jarfile` right? (2) MANIFEST.MF has an empty line after the Class-path: line -- i.e. you have end-of-line LF/CRLF then _another_ LF/CRLF? (3) Are you actually running on Java 7? Except paid updates starting around 7u150 IIRC, it doesn't support client TLS protocols above 1.0, which is now considered insecure, and most servers today including repo1.maven.org don't accept anything below 1.2; try `keytool -printcert -v -sslserver repo1.maven.org` from your runtime environment.